# Jmeter csv dataset values mismatched values in multi-threaded scenario

Tags: csv, testing, jmeter, dataset, load-testing

I have 2 threads running in JMeter each thread is reading values from different csv files. When I run the test plan, csv values belonging to thread 1 is used by thread 2 or vice versa. Hence, getting wrong results. I guess both the threads are using the same csv data set variable or for a thread group each csv dataset creates only one variable to store csv values no matter how many threads run. Whats wrong? Please Help.[Both threads are using same set of csv values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4xj2.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to all thread share same file use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) Sharing mode of `All threads`

> Sharing mode
> All threads - (the default) the file is shared between all the threads.

Meaning all threads will take values from only one set of data.